# WPF share column width between separate grids

Tags: wpf, grid, user-controls, styling

I have the following setup on my WPF UserControl:

```
<GroupBox>
  <Grid>
    ...
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

<GroupBox>
  <Grid>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="..." />
```

I'd like the second ColumnDefinition to be the same width as the first ColumnDefinition, but I don't want to set an explicit width.  Instead, I want both grids columns to automatically stretch to the width of the longest piece of content in either grid column!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It is possible by using [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx). Also check out [IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx).

```
<GroupBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <Grid>
    ...
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />

<GroupBox>
  <Grid>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
```

See [here](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen/archive/2007/08/27/21132.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Also ensure you set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the outer container of the two grids, otherwise it won't work