# Shared DataGridColumn Widths Across Multiple DataGrids

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid

I'm making multiple DataGrids in an application with the same set of columns and bindings. What I'm hoping to do is make all the DataGrid respond appropriately to a change in one DataGrid. If I change the size of one column, the corresponding columns in the other DGs should have the same width. It's somewhat similar to this question on S.O. ([WPF share column width between separate grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265595/wpf-share-column-width-between-separate-grids)) except for DataGrids, not Grids. I was hoping DataGrids would have a property similar to IsSharedSize like in Grid but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there a property I could access, or some alternative approach, to do what I'm trying to accomplish? Before anyone proposes this though, I cannot merge them all into one DataGrid, what I'm attempting means I can't put all the information in one DataGrid due to the nature of the application itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While sharing width is not possible in `DataGrid's` out-of-the-box, this is what I came across as the best way to handle such scenarios.

Create bindings between the source `DataGrid` columns and the target `DataGrid` columns widths. In my case I have two target `DataGrid's` (dgTarget1 and dgTarget2), so here is the code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < dgSource.Columns.Count; index++)
{
    Binding bindingWidth = new Binding();
    bindingWidth.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    bindingWidth.Source = dgSource.Columns[index];
    bindingWidth.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(dgTarget1.Columns[index], DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, bindingWidth);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(dgTarget2.Columns[index], DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, bindingWidth);
}
```

Comment: This solution basic works well. However, if I only want to do a OneWay binding I found that just doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party on this one, but I came across a similar scenario where I needed a Grid to sit below a DataGrid and share the same column spans. You can implement something similar to digitguy's answer using just XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgOne">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="One" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Two" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Three" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Four" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Columns[1].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Columns[2].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Columns[3].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

There's no reason that you couldn't do the same thing with two DataGrids.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgOne">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="One" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Two" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Three" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Four" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="One" Width="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Two" Width="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Three" Width="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Four" Width="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=dgOne}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```