# Cannot align textboxes inside grid properly among themselves

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, grid, alignment

I have the following `DataTemplate` where inside is a `Grid` with a 'TextBlock' and `TextBox` that I want to align to the center:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OneSettingsEntryTemplate" DataType="{x:Type templateHelper:InputText}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
                 Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In one of my `UserControls` I have the following code where I use the Template:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ControlForProjectSettings, Path=ViewModel}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeadingTextBlocksStyle}" 
               Text="Project settings"/>
    <ListView Background="#DAE7F5"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectSettingEntries}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OneSettingsEntryTemplate}">
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

When I run my application and display some items, the last item has a longer text and therefore the TextBox flips to the right.  [Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAutC.png)

I tried playing around with the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties inside the Grid or also using a `DockPanel` instead of a Grid but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265714/4112136

Comment: Yes, it fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this source: [WPF share column width between separate grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265595/wpf-share-column-width-between-separate-grids/2265714#2265714) I solved my problem.
I added the `IsSharedSizeScope` to my `Grid` and the `SharedSizeGroup` property to my columns.

```
    <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```