Display three Items with individual Click actions in one row of list view (c# WPF)
i'm fighting with the list view.
I have this ListView:
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="listViewCombined" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Margin="5">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>

and this is the template:
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dispo}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" MouseLeftButtonDown="DispoItem_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MATNR}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" MouseLeftButtonDown="MATNRItem_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MAKTG}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" MouseLeftButtonDown="MAKTGItem_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

The result from above code:

But I'm trying to put this in one row (like a group), and each new group in rows
each column needs to have individual their click actions.
First l have started, with 3 list views, but then each have their own vertical scrollbars, and as the items in one row belongs together. So i need a scroll view with three columns and each column has their own click action

You can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265714/1744164 or use a GridView

Can't reproduce layout, it shows as one row in one line

@MichałTurczyn that's interessting. How did you added items?

@SirRufo yes the GridView looks like what i'm searching for. I'll try it out.

the Grid View solved my Problem. I was able to do everithing i wanted. Thanks a lot

Make sure you don't use event handlers in your data templates as you are creating memory leak. All data templates with that event handler will never be disposed. Event handlers in WPF is a code smell.

First of all, you should take a look at MVVM pattern in WPF, and use ViewModel, commands and bindings :) But this is whole another topic.
To handle problem at hand, in order to define click handlers, it's easy. In XAML just do what you did, in code behind handler looks like this:
private void DispoItem_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}

And you can easily access the TextBlock via sender parameter.
But not sure if that addresses all your problems.
